Heston model: odd simulations of variance and asset price process path
I've done Monte Carlo simulations of asset and variance processes of the Heston model on Silver via a Full Truncation of Euler discretisation scheme to learn and see for myself how the simulation paths of both processes map out. However, the paths don't seem to look "correct". FYI, the workings are done in Excel for clarity and simplicity.
Without further ado, the formulas are as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
\ v_{t+\Delta t} &=& \ v_t + \kappa (\theta - \ v_t^{+}) \Delta t + \sigma \sqrt{\ v_t^{+} \Delta t} Z_V,
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
S_{t+\Delta t} = S_t \exp \left( \left(\mu - \frac{1}{2} v_t^{+} \right) \Delta t + \sqrt{v_t^{+} \Delta t}* \left( \rho Z_V + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2 \right) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
Where $v_{t+\Delta t}$ is the stochastic variance process and $S_{t+\Delta t}$ the asset price process. The following pictures are how both processes map out:



THE PROBLEM

Now even at first look, both simulation path processes look "wrong" as there are almost constant paths simulated. Interestingly enough, this happens when $v_{t+\Delta t}$ at any moment of the time step becomes negative. I understand that the Euler scheme makes the variance process more vulnerable to produce negative values.

As I understand it, when $v_{t+\Delta t}$ becomes negative, the next time step variance process only calculates on $v_{t}+κθ$ by virtue of absorption of the full truncation scheme. But the value does not seem to budge out of negative territory even after adjusting $κ$ values to close to 0 or even as high as 5.


The parameters and formulas in Excel are as below.
S0                          = 25.07400         //U17, column U
long-run variance (θ)       = 0.0487%          //$AJ$2
variance mean-reversion (κ) = 0.9464657        //$AJ$3
volatility of variance (σ)  = 0.361234915      //$AJ$4
correlation (ρ)             = -0.153147735     //$AJ$5, used in asset price process formula
starting variance (v0)      = 0.0988%          //$AJ$6 at time step 1 only
drift (μ)                   = 2.60%
time step (Δt)              = 1/10             //($V$12/$AE$12), 0.4 weeks time step each for 10 time steps total (4 weeks or 1 month price projection)

//Excel formulas for variance process v(t+Δt)
time step 1 = $AJ$6+$AJ$3*($AJ$2-$AJ$6)*($V$12/$AE$12)+$AJ$4*SQRT($AJ$6*($V$12/$AE$12))*AS17
t.step 2-10 = AG17+$AJ$3*($AJ$2-IF(AG17<0,0,AG17))*($V$12/$AE$12)+$AJ$4*SQRT(IF(AG17<0,0,AG17)*($V$12/$AE$12))*AT17

formula used= v(t)+κ[θ−v(t)]Δt + σ√[v(t)*Δt]Zv

//Excel formulas for price process S(t+Δt)
t.step 1-10 = U17*EXP(($C$26-IF(AG17<0,0,AG17)/2)*($V$12/$AE$12)+SQRT(IF(AG17<0,0,AG17)*($V$12/$AE$12))*($AJ$5*AS17+SQRT(1-$AJ$5^2)*NORM.S.INV(RAND())))

formula used= S(t)*exp[[μ−0.5v(t)]Δt+√[v(t)*Δt]∗[ρZv+√(1−ρ^2)*Z2]]


The calibration of parameters are not of concern as of now. I've done MLE for that but it returns too much of erratic price distribution and the p-value is about 65%. Granted I only used it on a small amount of data that is proportionate to the time steps to estimate the parameters.

But the main question is, what makes for a more "behaved" variance simulation so that the price projection is viable? Do I have any errors in my calculations? I've gone over them time and time again but I think everything seems in order.

It looks like your variance process goes to negative (ie evaluates to zero) and stays there, contrary to the expected behaviour where it goes up by $\nu_t + \kappa \theta$. This suggests a bug

@Rylan
My suspicions of this bug/error are directed towards how I structured the conditional formula of the truncation. The initial logic in the formula simply focuses on evaluation of the variance process but in fact, there ARE negative $v_{t+\Delta t}$ values. I have since corrected the formula to immediately replace the negative value to 0 by adjusting the formula to =IF((AG17+$AJ$3*($AJ$2-IF(AG17<0,0,AG17))*($V$12/$AE$12)+$AJ$4*SQRT(IF(AG17<0,0,AG17)*($V$12/$AE$12))*AT17)<0,0,AG17+$AJ$3*($AJ$2-IF(AG17<0,0,AG17))*($V$12/$AE$12)+$AJ$4*SQRT(IF(AG17<0,0,AG17)*($V$12/$AE$12))*AT17).

@Rylan The above correction has somewhat given more stable projections of the price and variance process ($v_{t+\Delta t}$ bounded by $max(0,x)$) and no more negative variance values in the graph as seen previously, though there are some paths that still exhibit constant drift paths with minimal linearity.
My question now is: does the logic of full truncation evaluates a constant drift (Variance process) of $κθ$ or $κθΔt$ (proportional to the time step) whenever $v_{t+\Delta t}$ is negative?
